# How to add colour to the Azure pipeline console?

Tags: java, azure, logging, azure-pipelines

I'm able to add colour to my local Intellij console using the XML file below but I'm not adding any colour to the console output in my Azure pipeline.

I'm following this tutorial:  (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/sdk/logging-logback).

The Azure console is using the default colours but picking up the layout specified in the XML.

Is there something I need to set in Azure for the colours to work?

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration level="${LOG_LEVEL}">

    <!-- disable startup logging for logback -->
    <statusListener class="ch.qos.logback.core.status.NopStatusListener"/>

    <property name="USER_HOME" value="logs"/>

    <appender name="STDOUT_INFO" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
            <level>INFO</level>
            <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
            <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
        </filter>
            <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
                <Pattern>%blue([%d{ISO8601}]) %highlight(%green(%-5level)) %blue([%logger{100}]:) %green(%msg%n%throwable)
                </Pattern>
            </encoder>
    </appender>

    <!--    <logger name="app" level="DEBUG" additivity="true">-->
    <!--    </logger>-->

    <root additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT_INFO"/>
    </root>

</configuration>
```

**Dependencies**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Update:

I ended up using the solution below.

```
<appender name="STDOUT_WARN" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
            <level>WARN</level>
            <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
            <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
        </filter>
        <if condition='property("LOG_ENV").equals("LOCAL")'>
            <then>
                <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
                    <Pattern>%blue([%d{ISO8601, Europe/Paris}]) [%t] %blue([%logger{100}]:) %yellow(%msg%n%throwable)
                    </Pattern>
                </encoder>
            </then>
            <else>
                <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
                    <Pattern>##[WARNING][%d{ISO8601, Europe/Paris}] [%t] [%logger{100}]: %msg%n%throwable</Pattern>
                </encoder>
            </else>
        </if>
    </appender>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Colors on the pipeline are done a bit differently than the standard console. There is no DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, and CRITICAL because there is no filtering of the level to display.

Microsoft created several prefixes to the actual text you post. They add colors or sections and groups to the console. Basically, you need something like this:

```
##[group]Beginning of a group
##[warning]Warning message
##[error]Error message
##[section]Start of a section
##[debug]Debug text
##[command]Command-line being run
##[endgroup]
```

This is directly from [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands).